# Errow When Starting MySQL [UBUNTU 13.04]

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am having troubles starting MySQL Community Server. I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I have downloaded MySQL Community Server 5.6 the Debian package. I don't have any previous MySQL Versions installed.
I installed the package using this command `dpkg -i mysql-5.6.14-debian6.0-i686.deb` and it was successful.

I found the installation files in /opt/mysql. I opened /opt/mysql/server-5.6/supported-files and then typed: `./mysql.server start`.

I got the following error:

`The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/mysql/server-5.6/data/ubuntu.pid)`

How can I solve that problem?

Thank You.

Comment: why did you downlod the deb and not install the ubunutu package? Did you require the specific version?

Comment: remove the pid file then restart.

Comment: The MySQL Ubuntu package is not up to date. And I also want to be able to install the latest version freely not to wait for the Ubuntu package to get updated. As for removing the pid file, I don't know where the pid file is located. Is there anyway of knowing. I have found that you can type "mysql.server --pid-file" this will show me where the pid file is located but I can't do that. I also found out that the file my.cnf doesn't exist in /etc. Any suggestions